# Arabic in PyroCMS

Tags: pyrocms

When I save some arabic data using phpmyadmin, Its showing correctly in my CMS. But if I save some data using my CMS admin its showing something like below.

Ú©ÙÙØ¯Ú¯Ø§Ù Ø®Ø¯ÙØ§Øª Ø§Ø³ÙØ§Ø¯ Ø¨ÙØ§ Ø¯Ø§Ø±Ø ÙØ¬Ø±ÛØ§Ù Ø³ÛØ³ØªÙ Ø§ÙØªÙØ§Ù Ø§Ø³ÙØ§Ø¯ Ø¨ÙØ§ Ø¯Ø§Ø± Ù Ø³Ø§ÛØ±Ø§Ø´Ø®Ø§ØµÛ Ú©Ù Ø¯Ø§ÙØºØ§ÙØ³ØªØ§Ù Ø¨Ø§ÙÚ© ÙÛØªÙØ§ÙØ¯ ÙØ·Ø§Ø¨Ù Ø§Ø­Ú©Ø§Ù ÙØ§ÙÙÙ Ø¢ÙÙØ§ Ø±Ø§ ÙØ¸Ø§Ø±Øª ÙÙØ§ÛØ.

I converted my data using utf8_encode() before saving. But still its giving same result. Any master configuration or encoding to set ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

1. Page header `<head>` contains 
   `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`
2. db Collation is `utf8_general_ci`

Then use

```
mb_convert_encoding($str,'UTF-8');
```

[PHP docs for mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)